# Property not exsisting on a type in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a chatbox and for the send message functionality I have the following code:

```
function ChatRoom() {
  const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25);

  const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState('');
  const sendMessage = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { uid, photoURL } = auth.currentUser;

    await messagesRef.add({
      text: formValue,
      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      uid,
      photoURL,
    });

    setFormValue('');
  };
  console.log(messages);
  console.log(auth.currentUser);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {messages &&
          messages.map(msg => (
            <ChatMessage key={(msg as Message).id} message={msg} />
          ))}
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
        <input
          value={formValue}
          onChange={e => setFormValue(e.target.value)}
          placeholder='say something nice'
        />

        <button type='submit' disabled={!formValue}>
          ️
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here I am getting the error:
`Property 'uid' does not exist on type 'User | null'.`
and
`Property 'photoURL' does not exist on type 'User | null'.`
Now I get that I have to define an interface and do this. But two problems arise here.

1. How do I make the interface. I console logged `auth.currentUser` and it is a pretty big object with loads of stuff (using Firebase).

[image]

2. If I do create an interface how do I assign it? Doing something like:
      `const { uid, photoURL } = (auth.currentUser : User);` still gives an error where `User` is the name of my interface.

I am new to TypeScript with React and any would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction. Much thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here I am getting the error: Property 'uid' does not exist on type 'User | null'. and Property 'photoURL' does not exist on type 'User | null'. Now I get that I have to define an interface and do this.

You are thinking that you need to define an interface because your component doesn't know the type of `auth.currentUser`.  But that is not how that error message reads to me.  Typescript believes that the type of `auth.currentUser` is `User | null`.  So there is already a `User` type or interface, which presumably has a whole bunch of properties and probably already defines `uid` and `photoURL`.  That's not the issue.  The issue is the `| null` part.  `auth.currentUser` is **either** a `User` object representing the current user, **or it's `null`**.  You can't destructure it until you know that it's an object and not `null`.  That is what the error is saying.

So we need to check the value and make sure that we don't have `null`:

```
const sendMessage = async (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const user = auth.currentUser;

  if (user) {
    const { uid, photoURL } = user;

    await messagesRef.add({
      text: formValue,
      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      uid,
      photoURL,
    });

    setFormValue('');
    
  } else {
    // can handle error somehow
  }
};
```

Comment: hey thanks for the wonderful explanation! Can you also tell me what would one do in case I did have to make the user interface but did not want to define all the properties and just `uid` and `photoURL`? Much thanks :)

Comment: `const { uid, photoURL } = user as {uid: string; photoURL: string}`

Comment: After looking all over the place this explanation is just the best !